# How to make an oscillation animation in opengl qt

Tags: qt, opengl, animation

I'm trying to make a character make an oscillation move. That is, the character will start by rotating to a certain angle, say 60 degrees, and then slowly come back to an upright position then rotate to the opposite direction for an angle less than 60, say 55, and do it all again until the rotation angle reaches zero and the character stops. Currently I'm trying to achieve this by declaring global variables and checking them with if blocks and changing their value by 1 degrees in those blocks so that each time the timer calls paintgl it decreases the angle by 1 degree and draws the object thus making it look like it's slowly rotating. I'm having trouble with stopping the character. This is the part of my code that handles it;

```
  glRotatef(j,0,1,0);
glRotatef(k,0,1,0);

if(flag)
{
    j = j + 2;
    if (j == 0)
     {
        k = 60;
        flag = !flag;

    }
}

if(!flag)
{

    k = k - 2;
    if(k == 0)
    {
        j = -60;
        flag = !flag;
    }
}

gluCylinder(player, 1,1,8,100,100);
```

Here the cylinder is my character and the if blocks are increasing/decreasing the global variables j and k. j is initialized to -60 and k is initialized to 60.

How can I make this thing work and how can I stop it.

Answer (score 0):

Are `k` and `j` floating point variables? If so, exact comparisons won't work, as floats are inherently imprecise. You'll have to take a difference and test if it's below a certain threshold.

However for simple oscillations, I'd just stick the time into a sine function and use the output of that (in the range -1…1) as input to a function that scaled and offsets to the desired animation state.

The universal method of doing this would be implementing a animation curve system. I.e. you can input parameters used to construct piecewise interpolation functions that take as input variable time, and as output variable the interpolated values as parametized by the user, i.e. you. Search for "animation curve system" for the details.

Comment: k and j are ints also the comparison isn't the issue. what i want to do is to make the character lean to the ground for an angle by the click of a mouse and when the mouse is released, the character will slowly go upright and lean on to the other direction, then slowly go upright again and lean on to the first direction and so on. it will lean a bit less each time until it will stop. I'm not sure if sine function has a part in this. Also since I'm really new on opengl, I don't know about interpolation functions or animation curves. It would be better if there's a simpler way to do it.

Comment: @user1432581: Interpolation functions and animation curves have **nothing** to do with OpenGL. They're basic animation techniques. And yes, you can do that damped oscillator with a sine and a exponential. The equation for this would be y(t) = sin(t a) exp(-t k). A damped oscillator does not move linear between it's extremal positions.